# Proving Integrability Of Functions

Tags: calculus

Prove that if there is a bounded function $f(x)$ such that for every $\epsilon$ there exists a partition of $[a, b]$ such that $U-L<\epsilon$ then the function is Riemann Integrable on the interval $[a, b]$ where $U$ and $L$ denote the upper and lower sum respectively.
$$$$Suppose that $U_x$ and $L_x$ denote  the upper sum and lower sum of a partition with norm $x$. Now given that for every $\epsilon$ there exists a partition with a particular norm say $P$ such that $U_P-L_P <\epsilon$ and as we know that the upper sum decreases and the lower sum increases as the norm of the partition becomes smaller, so for all partitions of $[a, b]$ with norm $\delta<P$ we have $$U_{\delta}-L_{\delta}\leq U_P-L_P<\epsilon$$. Now as the upper sum is an increasing function of the norm of the partition and also as the upper sum is bounded from above and below as the function is bounded and the interval $[a, b]$ is finite so the upper sum must has some least lower bound say $I$ then we have $$\lim_{\Delta x_{max} \to 0} U = I$$ $$$$(As if a function is increasing and bounded in $(c, c+a)$ for some $a>0$ then the limit $\lim_{x \to c}g(x)$ exists and is equal to the least lower bound of the function on the interval $(c, c+a)$) $$$$ and also as $U-L<\epsilon$ whenever the norm is less than $P$ where $\epsilon$ is arbitrarily small so we have $$\lim_{\Delta x_{max} \to 0} L=I$$ Hence the function $f(x)$ is Integrable on the interval $[a, b]$ and its integral is equal to $I$.
$$$$I want to know that is the proof I have done above is correct or not? Plz help me.

Comment: "as we know that the upper sum decreases and the lower sum increases as the norm" - how do we know that?. A second problem is that $U$ is not actually a *function* of its norm, so your argument that $I$ exists doesn't work as stated. The easiest work-around is to take the limit of some sequence of upper sums (for which the argument does work), then show all the other upper sums converge to the same limit.

Comment: It can be proved that as the norm decreases the upper sum decreases and the lower sum increases

Comment: "It *can be proved*" - stop weasel-wording and prove it.

Comment: Consider a partition if $[a, b]$ with $x_1, x_2, ......, x_n$ as the points of division and suppose the partition is made more finer by adding a point $x_r$ between the points $x_{k-1}$ and $x_k$ then difference in the new upper sum and previous upper sum equals $f(M_1)(x_r-x_{k-1})+f(M_2)(x_k-x_r)-f(M)(x_k-x_{k-1}) \leq f(M)(x_r-x_{k-1}+x_k-x_r)-f(M)(\Delta x_k) \leq 0$ where $M_1, M_2, M$ denote the maximum value of the function in the intervals $[x_{k-1}, x_r]$, $[x_r, x_k]$ and $[x_{k-1}, x_k]$ respectively

Comment: That is a start, but suppose I give you another partition $y_i$ with lesser norm that the $x_i$, which only shares the two endpoints $a, b$ with the $x_i$. How can you be sure that the upper sum for this partition is $\le$ the upper sum for the $x_i$?

Comment: I don't know how to prove this can you plz help?

Comment: Also "the upper sum is a function of the norm" for that part if we choose any sequence of the upper sum which makes it a function of the norm converging to $I$ then will that reasoning be correct?

Comment: This is why I don't prefer the $\|P\| \to 0$ method of defining Riemann integration. This is much less difficult if instead you define it as $\exists P$ such that $U(P') - L(P') < \epsilon$ for all refinements  $P'$ of $P$. It is easy to show $U(P') < U(P)$ when $P'$ is a refinement of $P$. But when they are unrelated except for having a smaller norm, it's a pain. You can do it by comparing the sums for $\{x_i\}$ and for $\{y_i\}$ to the sum for their union $\{x_i\}\cup\{y_i\}$. But it gets really fiddly.

Comment: And "the upper sum is a function of the norm" for that part if we choose any sequence of the upper sum which makes it a function of the norm converging to $I$ then will that reasoning be correct?

Comment: What you do is choose a sequence of partitions $P_n$ with decreasing norms $\|P_n\| \to 0$, and take their upper sums $U_n = U(P_n)$. Because the norms are decreasing, so are the $U_n$, and they are bounded below, so they have an infimum, which acts as your limit. Then you prove that the limit for all partitions has to converge to this same value.

Comment: So we can choose a sequence of upper sums as a function of norm and then proceed

Comment: You can proceed to showing that there is a value $I$ to which *this sequence* converges. Then you can proceed to showing that the general limit *over all partitions* must converge to the same limit. Once you have shown that, then you can proceed with the rest of your proof. (You will need to do the same for the lower limit, but there are shortcuts, such as applying the upper limit result to $-f(x)$.)

Comment: Can we do like this : As Upper sum is bounded from below so it must have an least lower bound say $I$ then consider any $\epsilon>0$ we have some value of the upper sum say $y_0$ in the interval $[I, I+\epsilon)$ and let the the norm of the partition for this upper sum be $a$ then for all partitions with norms less than $a$ we have the value of upper sum $\leq y_0$ and hence we can keep the upper sum within any neighbourhood of $I$ by keeping the norms of partition less than a particular value and hence we have "upper sum converges to $I$"

Comment: Yes, that is a better approach than the sequence, making it easier to prove the general limit. But it needs to be adjusted because the upper sum *does not necessarily decrease* with the partition norm. I was having trouble creating the argument, so I used the issue I was running into to look for counter-examples, and found one. I'm posting it in answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but it has been a while since I had looked at this. The concept that the upper sum always decreases and lower sum always increases as the partition norm decreases is false.

Consider the interval $[0,6]$ with partitions $P_2 = \{0,3,6\}$ and $P_3 = \{0,2,4,6\}$, so $\|P_2\| = 3$ and $\|P_3\|= 2$. Let $$f(x) = \begin{cases}0,& x\in[0,3]\\1,&x\in(3,6]\end{cases}$$

The upper sum for $P_2$ is $$U_2 = 0\cdot 3 + 1 \cdot 3 = 3$$. The upper sum of $P_3$ is $$U_3 = 0\cdot 2 + 1\cdot 2 + 1 \cdot 2 = 4$$

This is a case where $U_3 > U_2$ even though $\|P_3\| < \|P_2\|$.

Comment: Your counter example also makes it false that making partitions finer decreases Upper sum and increases lower sum

Comment: No it doesn't. $P_3$ is not a refinement of $P_2$. It isn't hard at all to show that the upper sum of a refinement is $\le$ the upper sum of the original partition. the sum for the original partition can be converted to a sum over each of the refinement intervals, but using the max value for the entire original partition interval instead of over each refinement interval. Since this max covers the refinement interval range, it will be $\ge$ the maxes for the refinement intervals. So the sum is $\ge$ as well.

Comment: But in the case of norm what to do?

Comment: Because $f$ is bounded, you can place an upper limit on how much two upper sums for partitions with norms $< \epsilon$ can differ from each other - a limit that goes to $0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: Can you plz show me how to do this?